# How do I do a .htaccess rewrite that masks the forwarded URL?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a url that is www.blahblah.com/something

That is a remote service, I don't have anything to do with it.

How can I use .htaccess on my own server and rewrite from www.myurl.com so that the content displayed is all www.blahblah.com/something, but the address bar still reads www.myurl.com

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible with foreign urls.

You can, however, do this locally. For example, look at this htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^some/test/url$ index.php?some=test&or=url [L]
```

In this scenario, if you visit `www.myurl.com/some/test/url` it will show as such on the browser, but your server will actually be running `index.php` in your document root with the parameters `some=test&or=url`.

This is only possible for scripts running on your server. You cannot do this on another server/domain.  If you try this (eg, by changing `index.php?some=test&or=url` in the example above to `http://www.blahblah.com/something`), then apache will just redirect the browser to that url.

htaccess (Apache) makes the connection to the user, and the user is expecting a response from YOUR server. If you try to load content from another server, Apache would have to make that connection, load the resulting HTML or whatever, and pass it back to you.  But this gets messy, especially when you get into cookies, SSL, javascript, etc.

My question is: why do you actually need this? I'm not sure I understand why it is a problem if the user's url changes.  If it's a service you have no control over, why is it so bad to just send them to it?

You might want to research more about cache servers, or using PHP to to make the http call to the server you want and "pass through" the content, assuming you know beyond a doubt there will be no issues with cookies or SSL or whatever.  But again, why not just send them to the proper URL?

Comment: Hmm...well the myurl.com is my server.  The external service is not as wellformed and we want to build up presence on the Internet under our domain....I believe I've seen it done before...but maybe not....

Comment: I've done lots of things where we pull in a remote service, but it's always in PHP, through some type of REST-ful call or API.  This is not possible to be done on the Apache/htaccess level, but will be a more complicated solution using a fair amount of programming.

Comment: Without knowing specifically what the external service is, what exactly you are trying to do, and how much control/access you have to the external service (specifically on the back-end), I'm afraid I can't be of more help :/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^DomainA.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://DomainB.com/$1 [P]
```

It works for me.

Source: http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/htaccess/redirect-without-changing-url

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Answer (score 0):

mod_rewrite is the right way.

1. Make sure it is mod_rewrite is activated in our apache conifiguration.
2. add to the .htaccess

   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.blahblah\.com$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.myurl.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond defines the condition. In this case if the http_Host is  www.blahblah.com
RewriteRule defines what to do. In this case forward to your target domain. $1 is the rest of your URL

More Details you can find here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: is this a redirect or a rewrite...in other words, in the navigation wlil it show http://www.myurl.com, but the page served will ceom from www.blahblah.com/something/something?

Comment: I noticed you just did a rewrite with the URI, but not with the directories for blahblah.com/something else....